# Как вывести в консоль не каждый цикл, а конечное число циклов?

Tags: java, циклы, for

```
import java.lang.math;
public class Vika { 
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
    int numberOfSpaces = 0;
    int numberOfDots = 0;
    int numberOfSymbols = 0;
    String s = "I read some interesting books. What books? Flowers for Elgernone;";

    for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++) {
        if(s.charAt(i)!='.' && s.charAt(i)!=' ');
        numberOfSymbols++;
        System.out.print(numberOfSymbols);  
            }
        }
}
```

Вывод в консоли:
1234567891011121314151617181920212223242526272829303132333435363738394041424344454647484950515253545556575859606162636465

> Как сделать, чтобы выводилось только число 65

Comment: Вынесите строку `System.out.print(numberOfSymbols)` за цикл. А если вам нужно  только число символов, то это в одну строчку делается

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вынеси эту строку:

```
System.out.print(numberOfSymbols);
```

за пределы цикла for()

```
for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++) {
    if(s.charAt(i)!='.' && s.charAt(i)!=' ');
    numberOfSymbols++;
    //Отсюда убрали 
}
//Сюда перенесли
System.out.print(numberOfSymbols);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TEST {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numberOfSpaces, numberOfDots, numberOfSymbols;
        String s = "I read some interesting books. What books? Flowers for Elgernone;";
        numberOfSpaces = s.length() - s.replace(" ", "").length();
        numberOfDots = s.length() - s.replace(".", "").length();
        numberOfSymbols = s.length();
        System.out.println(numberOfSpaces);
        System.out.println(numberOfDots);
        System.out.println(numberOfSymbols);
/*
        for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            if(s.charAt(i) != '.' && s.charAt(i) != ' ');
            if(i + 1 == s.length()){
                numberOfSymbols = i + 1;
                System.out.print(numberOfSymbols);    
            }
        }
*/
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте цикл:

```
for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    switch(s.charAt(i)) { 
     case ' ':
        numberOfSpaces++; 
        break;
     case '.':
        numberOfDots++;
        break;
     default:
        numberOfSymbols++;         
}

//распечатка после окончания цикла
System.out.println(numberOfSpaces+", "+numberOfDots+", "+numberOfSymbols);
```